# Why my php scripts doesn't get executed?

Tags: php

I have this html page on my pc

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost/welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this php script in my /var/www folder

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

My php script is correct, but when I submit the output is only 
Welcome!
You are years old 
that is its not echoing the form.. ie. the script isnt getting the data. where should I put the welcome.php to output the correct data?

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($_POST);` in your welcome.php to see if you are getting any POST-data in your script?

Comment: When you say you have the HTML page on your PC and the script in your /var/www directory, you're talking about the same machine aren't you? I can't see why it wouldn't be working if they are...

Comment: Yes its the same machine.. but its not echoing data

Comment: does this: `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` echo `test`?

Comment: No.. this doesnt echo test.

Comment: It works now :o ,, I dont even know what I have done.. But works now after I ran this command 
   <code>sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server</code>

Comment: LOL. You didn't have php5 installed, thus php code won't compile nor run.

Answer (score 2):

#### No PHP installed.

It appears that you did not have PHP installed. The `.php` files will then be served to the browser as if it were regular HTML files. The `<?php` "tag" isn't recognized by your browser, so the content in it will not be rendered. That explains what you're seeing and makes it look like PHP is malfunctioning.

As you noted yourself in your comment, installing PHP solved it. Two (out of many other) ways to install PHP with Apache:

- `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` (the caret (`^`) is not a typo). Will install the full LAMP stack (Apache, MySQL, PHP).
- Install the [libapache2-mod-php5 [image: Install libapache2-mod-php5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libapache2-mod-php5) package. This is solely PHP5 as a module with Apache.